# EF6 Code first database table not created

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have a new database set up with this connection string:

```
<add name="XName" connectionString="Data Source=XX\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XDatabase;User ID=dbo_XDatabase;Password=Password1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I added a model, added a migration and ran `update-database` but the table was not created.

Here's the migration code generated:

```
public partial class MagicWombat : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Languages",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    Code = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10),
                    IsEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.Languages");
    }
}
```

Everything seemed to run successfully, including my seed method. I've tested the connection to the database and it works fine. Now if I create another migration it doesn't generate code for my table again, so it seems to think it's been created successfully when it hasn't.

Why was my table not created?

Comment: you say _I've tested the connection to the database and it works fine._ can you elaborate, have you tried actually logging into the DB with the user account from the connection string and creating and seeding a test DB and table.  I would expect a permissions issue to throw an exception, but it's worth a check, in case it just isn't set with high enough permissions to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping my database and re-creating it solved the issue. Weird..